# Render child nodes after mounted lifecycle event in Vue

Tags: javascript, vue.js, three.js, vuejs2, vue-component

I need a hand with implementing Three.js to a Vue project of mine.

So far, I managed to divide the parts of three's declarative code to smaller components which do not render anything, so the code looks more like the WebGL is using HTML to add parts to the scene.

Currently, it looks like this:

```js
<template>
    <div class="scene" ref="sceneContainer">
        <div v-if="canRenderParts" class="scene__parts">
            <Camera></Camera>
            <Light></Light>
            <Controls></Controls>
        </div>
    </div> 
<template>

<script>
    data () {
        return { 
            canRenderParts: false
        };
    },
    mounted () {
        // Scene
        this.$store.commit('setScene', new THREE.Scene());

        // Renderer
        this.$store.commit('setRenderer', new THREE.WebGLRenderer({
            antialias: true,
            alpha: true
        }));
        this.$store.state.renderer.setSize(
            this.$refs.sceneContainer.offsetWidth,
            this.$refs.sceneContainer.offsetHeight
        );
        this.$refs.sceneContainer.appendChild(
            this.$store.state.renderer.domElement
        );

        this.animate(); // basic animation loop

        // Bootstrap other parts of the scene
        this.canRenderParts = true;
    }
    // ...
</script>
```

Now, I want to remove the `canRenderParts` hack, but I'm not sure if it's possible. `canRenderParts` is there because I'm bootstrapping Three.js in `mounted` lifecycle event (as it's using the `$refs` which are not available in `create` lifecycle event). If I render other parts of the scene before the canvas is created (before `renderer.domElements` gets appended to `sceneContainer`) I cannot see them, that's why there's a wrapper which triggers the creation of them after the canvas is created.

I was thinking about using the `render` function for template rendering, but I'm not sure if it would be any help.

So, I'm wondering... what should I do in a situation like that? Is there any more "native" approach of initializing components dynamically?

Thank you in advance.

Comment: change `mountned` to `mounted`

Comment: @petey sorry for the typo